# Combination of conditions in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, for-loop, if-statement, switch-statement

I have 5 check boxes on my form and for each of the check box there's a separate condition to validate. And user can select any number of checkboxes. For each of the selected check box I have to execute it's corresponding condition.
Example

If checkbox1 then condition 1

If checkbox2 then condition 2

If checkbox3 then condition 3

If checkbox1 & checkbox2 then condition 1 & condition2

If checkbox1 & checkbox3 then condition 1 & condition3

If checkbox2 & checkbox3 then condition 2 & condition3

and so on...
Till all combinations of all checboxes

I want to avoid multiple if statements can anyone suggest me better logic for the same in JavaScript.

TIA

Comment: well, you just need to check each checkbox individually, and do each condition individually ... seeing as any time cb1 is checked, condtion1 is whatever you mean by condition1 (so, it's 5 if statements) - you can't avoid 5 if statements for 5 checkboxes

Comment: Could you show your code? The first 3 if statements should be all you need.

Comment: @4castle - there are 5 in the question, 3 in the example :p I feel all Monty Python mixing up 3's and 5's like that :p

Comment: There are actually 5 checkboxes..but I don't write all the if statement here

Comment: You can have a selector for all checked checkboxes (maybe with a particular class: `document.querySelectorAll('input.foo:checked')`). Loop over them and make sure the condition for each is true, correlate the condition with the checkbox name or some other attribute value.

Comment: @JaromandaX but how to check combinations of checkbox3 checkbox4 checkbox5 or checkbo2 cb4 cb5..like user can select any number of checkboxes

Comment: why? your pseudo code suggests "condition1" if checkbox1 is checked ... regardless ... so you just need to check each one in turn, trust me, it will work

Comment: if you handle each condition separately then no need to check for combination, as it will be handled in separate condition.

Comment: Would you like to either delete this question or see if any answers fit? :)

Answer (score 1):

Handle each condition individually

You can see from the output that your "conditions" marry up with the checkbox state

```js
function blah(checkbox1, checkbox2, checkbox3, checkbox4, checkbox5, str) {
    if(checkbox1) {
        str += ':condition1';
    }
    if(checkbox2) {
        str += ':condition2';
    }
    if(checkbox3) {
        str += ':condition3';
    }
    if(checkbox4) {
        str += ':condition4';
    }
    if(checkbox5) {
        str += ':condition5';
    }
    return str;
}
console.log(blah(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 'checkbox1'));
console.log(blah(0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 'checkbox2'));
console.log(blah(0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 'checkbox3'));
console.log(blah(1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 'checkbox1, checkbox2'));
console.log(blah(1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 'checkbox1, checkbox3'));
console.log(blah(1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 'checkbox1, checkbox2, checkbox3'));
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try putting each checkbox's condition into its own function and storing the function by the checkbox's `id` as the key in a javascript object:

```js
function run() {
  var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input.condition:checked')

  var conditions = {
    'one': function(data) {
      return data.one;
    },
    'two': function(data) {
      return data.two;
    },
    'three': function(data) {
      return data.three;
    }
  };

  var someJson = {
    'one': true,
    'two': true,
    'three': false
  };

  if (!checkboxes.length) {
    console.log('Please select at least one checkbox');
    return;
  }

  for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
    var checkbox = checkboxes[i];
    var id = checkbox.id;
    var conditionFunc = conditions[id];
    if (typeof conditionFunc !== 'function' || !conditionFunc(someJson)) {
      console.log('Failed on condition for checkbox: ' + id);
      return;
    }
  }
  console.log('Completed all conditions successfully!');
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" class="condition" id="one">One</input><br>
<input type="checkbox" class="condition" id="two">Two</input><br>
<input type="checkbox" class="condition" id="three">Three</input><br>
<button onclick="run()">Run</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what i would do (for easier use it requires jQuery):
Add a data attribute to all your checkboxes that pair them to a condition (like you said: connect1 to condition1).
Store all your conditions in an object, where the keys are the numbers used in the data attributes:
HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" data-number="1">
```

JavaScript:

```
var conditions = {
    "1": true //some condition;
}
```

Then keep a track on your checked checkboxes:

```
var checked = [];
$(".input[type='checkbox']").on("click", function(){
   var number = $(this).attr("data-number");
   var index = checked.indexOf(number);
   if(index > -1){
       arr.splice(index, 1); //delete if already there (unchecked)
   } else {
       arr.push(index); //add if not already there (checked)
   }
});
```

Now how to determine what conditions have to be applied:
Make sure to put the following code inside a function and always call it, when you need to check for the conditions:

```
var passed = true;
for(var i = 0; i < checked.length && passed; i++){
    passed = conditions[checked[i].toString()]; // Assuming that condition1, ..., condition n must be true
}

if(passed){
    alert("All conditions where true");
} else {
    alert("One condition was false"); 
}
```

Please note:
You might want to redefine the conditions object as soon as you check, because dom manipulations want automatically update the conditions object.
Please ask in the comments if something is unclear.
This solution is capable of infinite conditions (well not more than the highest number javascript is capable of by default but still enough)